# Execute "grunt serve" on windows service

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a windows server PC with nodejs installed.

I need to execute my grunt application automatically at startup, and I would like to use a windows service.

A workaround could be to launch "cmd" within "startup" folder with a link, but windows service is better... is there a way?

thank you in advance

Luca

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: No, I still launch the command via dos prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with winser:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/winser

**Example:**

If your gruntfile is on `D:\app` and you want that the gruntfile is executed in `D:\app (cwd)` and grunt isnt in your PATH `(grunt [not grunt-cli] is installed locally)`

```
winser -i --startcmd "node D:\app\node_modules\grunt\bin\grunt --base D:\app --gruntfile D:\app\gruntfile.js"
```